# Kubernetes Orchestration depending upon number of rows/records/Input Files

Tags: kubernetes

Requirement is to orchestrate ETL containers depending upon the number of records present at the Source system (SQL/Google Analytics/SAAS/CSV files).

To explain take a Use Case:- ETL Job has to process 50K records present in SQL server, however, it takes good processing time to execute this job by one server/node as this server makes a connection with SQL, fetches the data and process the records.

Now the problem is how to orchestrate in Kubernetes this ETL Job so that it scales up/down the containers depending upon number of records/Input. Like the case discussed above if there are 50K records to process in parallel then it should scale up the containers process the records and scales down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would generally use a queue of some kind and Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA) to watch the queue size and adjust the queue consumer replicas automatically. Specifics depend on the exact tools you use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read more about it and understood the concept. I will carry out a poc around it and confirm the results.